# Service Worker Fails on caches.open()

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm trying to get a basic service worker up and running.

The problem I have is that when I run "caches.open()", the browser throws a

```
sw.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unexpected internal error
```

Commenting out the caches.open removes the exception.

How can I get more information from the browser to tell me what's wrong?

Here's the service worker and registration code.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'pwacache-v1';

var urlsToCache = [
    '/',
    'main.css'
];


self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    // Perform install steps
    console.log('install');
    try {
        event.waitUntil(getFiles());
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
});

function getFiles() {
    console.log('opening: ' + CACHE_NAME );
    /*
        triggers Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unexpected internal error
    */
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
        return Promise.all(
            urlsToCache.map(function (url) {
                console.log(url);
                return cache.add(url).catch(function (reason) {
                    console.log([url + "failed: " + String(reason)]);
                });
            }) // end of map
        );
    });
    console.log('waiting 3...')
}
```

And the registration code

```
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
  });
}
```

I do see the sw.js registered in Chrome's 'Application' tab.

Comment: The error only occurs when Visual Studio is launching the Google Chrome Browser.  If I manually launch Chrome, or use Chrome Igconito Window, or use Microsoft Edge, no DOM Exception.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise from `getFiles()` in order for the `event.waitUntil()` to actually wait for the async work.  So I recommend returning the promise returned by your promise chain started with `caches.open()`.

Without this its possible the service worker is being terminated before the async work can complete.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll have to figure out how to do that, so I can try it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add the `return` keyword before your `caches.open()` call.

Comment: Thx Ben, appreciate your insight, and programming assistance.